# Strange messages from Gmail regarding my recovery email address changing

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, gmail

I have several google/gmail accounts for various purposes.   This morning I woke up to the following message from google saying the recovery email address had changed.   Here is the email

> ```
> Your recovery email address changed   
> Hi VNS娱乐城876502.com注册送88元,网上最火爆的游戏平台,超好赢钱游戏,
> The recovery email for your Google Account g*****737@gmail.com was recently changed.
>
> Don't recognize this activity?
> Review your recently used devices now.
> Best,
> The Google Accounts team
> This email can't receive replies. For more information, visit the Google Accounts Help Center.
> ```

The thing is, neither VNS娱乐城876502.com注册送88元,网上最火爆的游戏平台,超好赢钱游戏 nor g*****737@gmail.com are email addresses that I have ever used before.   Why would I receive a notice about an email recovery account I do not own having the backup email changed?

Here is a screenshot[image]

From all appearances it looks like the email is actually from google.

Then at 12:01 AM last night I get the following email telling me someone is trying to login to an actual email account I do own.   Luckily I use randomized passwords plus MFA for everything that allows 2 factor auth.  Any time someone tries to login to any of my google accounts from any computer that I have never logged into before will kick off the MFA request.

> Review blocked sign-in attempt     You received this message because
>   r*****6@gmail.com is listed as the recovery email for
>   e*****e@gmail.com. If e*****e@gmail.com is
>   not your Google Account, click here to disconnect from that account
>   and stop receiving emails.     Hi John, Google just blocked someone from
>   signing into your Google Account e*****e@gmail.com from
>   an app that may put your account at risk. Less secure app Sunday,
>   October 23, 2016 12:01 AM (Pacific Daylight Time) California, USA*
>   Don't recognize this activity? If you didn't recently receive an error
>   while trying to access a Google service, like Gmail, from a non-Google
>   application, someone may have your password.
>
> SECURE YOUR ACCOUNT
>
> Are you the one who tried signing in? Google will continue to block
>   sign-in attempts from the app you're using because it has known
>   security problems or is out of date. You can continue to use this app
>   by allowing access to less secure apps, but this may leave your
>   account vulnerable.
>
> Best, The Google Accounts team

I have already went ahead and changed my password for the account in question, but I was wondering if there was any further action I should take to secure my gmail account past what I am already doing?

Comment: I'd try and contact Google as well. The long strings make me thing they have input validation issue somewhere.

Comment: Is it possible someone used *your* email address as a recovery address for another account? Could've been by mistake or a deliberate attempt to try and phish you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suspicious email. I would suggest you check and analyze header of the email you recieved and verify if its sent from google. Also check IP of the sender.
Check this link for more info;  http://www.howtogeek.com/108205/htg-explains-what-can-you-find-in-an-email-header/

Comment: Is there any way to 100% verify?

Answer (score -2):

Google sends this when someone try to reset your recovery email.

You need to do the following.

1. Change your password to a strong one from a trusted computer. Enable
2. 2 factor authentication on the google account.
3. Change the recovery email back to the original one.